# issue regarding variable scope

Tags: c++, scope

I have trouble grasping the concept of variable scope. What is acceptable and what is not acceptable? I am aware that I've left out all of the graphics related code, and I am aware that I have an infinite game loop, but bear with me:

```
#include "LList.h"
#include "Snake.h"
#undef main



int main()
{

float dt;               // time since last update.
int start_time;
bool paused = false;
float originalTime = 1.0f;
float timer = originalTime;
Snake p1Snake(10, false);



    // Start the 'stopwatch'
    start_time = SDL_GetTicks();

    ///////////////////////
    // The 'game loop'   //
    ///////////////////////
    while (!done)
    {
        //////////////////////
        // Update variables //
        //////////////////////
        // Update the dt value (to be the time since the last update)
        dt = (SDL_GetTicks() - start_time) / 1000.0f;
        start_time = SDL_GetTicks();

            //increment the movement timer
        timer-=dt;
        if(timer<=0) When timer hits zero the snake is moved north.
            {
                p1Snake.goNorth();
                timer = originalTimer; //reset timer.
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Okay! So my question is about the variable 'originalTimer'. It is out of scope where the timer is reset, so what can I do differently? Sorry if this is an extremely elementary question.

Comment: Did you mean `originalTime`?

Comment: Assuming you actually mean `originalTime`, then why do you think it is out of scope?

Comment: That `#undef main` looks so suspicious I can't even begin to describe it.

Comment: where u have declared originalTimer? in your program

Comment: The scope of all of those variables is the entire `main` function.

Comment: That is so embarrasing! My compiler said it was out of scope, but my problem was I typed "originalTime" instead of "originalTimer".

Comment: I thought the scope was okay, but I was totally confused and thrown off by that stupid error message.

Comment: @chris I don't even know what '#undef main' does, but it's always there when I start a new project.

Comment: @DebrisHauler, Out of curiosity, what's generating the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be typo, but there are two different variables `originalTime` and `originalTimer`

Changing in code below should work for you..

```
timer = originalTime; //reset timer.
```

Answer (score 2):

You used different names. `originalTime` and `originalTimer`

```
#include "LList.h"
#include "Snake.h"
#undef main



int main()
{

    float dt;               // time since last update.
    int start_time;
    bool paused = false;
    float originalTimer = 1.0f;  //Changed to originalTimer
    float timer = originalTimer; //Changed to originalTimer
    Snake p1Snake(10, false);

    // Start the 'stopwatch'
    start_time = SDL_GetTicks();

    ///////////////////////
    // The 'game loop'   //
    ///////////////////////
    while (!done)
    {
        //////////////////////
        // Update variables //
        //////////////////////
        // Update the dt value (to be the time since the last update)
        dt = (SDL_GetTicks() - start_time) / 1000.0f;
        start_time = SDL_GetTicks();

        //increment the movement timer
        timer-=dt;
        if(timer<=0) //When timer hits zero the snake is moved north.
        {
            p1Snake.goNorth();
            timer = originalTimer; //reset timer.
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```